# Prevent Power Off and Lock

Tags: 18.04

I have a PC with Ubuntu 18.04 in a semi-public environment. There is a non-admin user account that can be used by anyone without logging in.

How can I prevent the user from shutting down the system, putting it in standby, or locking the screen?

Disabling the GUI buttons would be sufficient, if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this was a hard-to-google kind of issue, but after manually browsing through the settings with dconf-editor, I found what I had to change.

To prevent the user from logging out, locking the screen, or powering off the system, change three settings with these commands in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-log-out true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching true
```

Perhaps this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Hi @KalleElmer, will these 3 commands restrict the user to shutdown the system also? i guess your Question title is somewhat about shutdown??

Comment: Yes, but only in the graphical user interface. What happens is that the shutdown button in the top-right menu disappears. This is enough for me, because my users apparently aren't tech-savvy enough to find the button to turn the PC back on, which is the reason that I want to prevent shutdown from occuring in the first place. Standby is still available though, but it only takes a key press to recover from that.

Comment: Ehh, I would like to preserve Log Out, and Switch User, but disable all power operations specifically. Doesn't look like there's a matching `dconf` key even in Gnome 3.30 :/